# Conflict between jquery and prototype

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, conflict

I am using prototype and jquery, plus I'm creating a slide with another plugin which requires jquery.
Now try `jQuery.noConflict ()`, but still does not work.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j('#slides').slides({
        play: 5000,
        pause: 2500,
        hoverPause: true
    });
});
```

This is the error that gives me the chrome and it does not work the slide.

```
Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length
Object.extend.shift         prototype.js:464
d.extend.dequeue            jquery.min.js:16
d.fn.extend.dequeue         jquery.min.js:16
d.extend.each               jquery.min.js:16
d.fn.d.each                 jquery.min.js:16
d.fn.extend.dequeue         jquery.min.js:16
d.extend.speed.e.complete   jquery.min.js:16
d.fx.step                   jquery.min.js:16
g                           jquery.min.js:16
d.extend.tick
```

Comment: Look at the bottom-right-hand-corner of this page. There are tons of questions (somewhat related) to this one.

Comment: This answer explains the problem. Fix is to use a more recent version of prototype. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7736004/1042398

Answer (score 0):

Is this a problem of variable scope? Did you tried removing the "var" next to j to declare j as global? Hope that helps.

Comment: Previously I had already tried with $ j = jQuery.noConflict () and does not work.
I've read right here look similar problems and have tried several things and still can not work well.

Comment: I would be good if you post your code, or a simple example of it, a simple html page with the error, or a link.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

This is the page, will appreciate all the support.
http://mayanresidenciales.com/desarrollo/proyectos/index.php

Comment: I don't see javascript errors in the console. I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: ok, I think I'm wrong on the link because the link above redirects to the home in which I have no problems.
With this new link if you can see the page in which I get the error.

[Link] http://mayanresidenciales.com/desarrollo/setProject.php?p=26

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for all your support, in the end I solved using another plugin easySlider.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Ok... By the way... do you speak spanish? Porque de ser así hubiera sido más fácil en español jaja

Comment: Beto Aveiga => Jajaja definitivamente hubiera sido más fácil, la verdad casi no manejo el Ingles, para la próxima lo haré en español jajaja te agradezco.